# Inequality on "supremum" of product of functions

Tags: measure-theory, self-learning

Let $(A,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f$ a measurable real
function. Define $\text{ess} \sup (f)=\inf\{c\in \mathbb{R}:\mu(\mid f\mid>c)=0\}$ and $\text{ess} \inf (f)=\sup\{c\in \mathbb{R}:\mu(\mid f\mid<c)=0\}$.

I want to show that $\text{ess} \sup (fg)\leq \text{ess} \sup(f). \text{ess} \sup(g)$, when both sides are nonnegative.

Can you give me a hint to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it's enough to show that $\mu(|fg|> \text{ess sup}(f) \cdot \text{ess sup}(g)) = 0$. If $|fg| > \text{ess sup}(f)\cdot \text{ess sup}(g)$, then either $|f|>\text{ess sup}(f)$ or $|g|> \text{ess sup}(g)$ (why is this?).

To complete the proof, you need to show that $\mu(|f| > \text{ess sup}(f)) = 0$ (and the same will follow for $g$). Two facts are important here:

- $|f|> \text{ess sup}(f)$ if and only if there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f|> \text{ess sup}(f)+\frac{1}{n}$.
- By definition of infimum, for every $n$, there exists $c_n < \text{ess sup}(f)+\frac{1}{n}$ such that $\mu(|f|>c_n)=0$.

Use these two facts to conclude that $\mu(|f|>\text{ess sup}(f))=0$.

Comment: Write ess$\sup (f)=a$ and ess$\sup (g)=b$. You are telling me to bound  $\mu(\mid fg\mid >ab)\leq \mu (\{\mid f\mid>a\}\cup \{\mid g\mid>b\})$, and than conclude that this upper bound is zero? Nice strategy

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is a succinct way to put it.

Comment: Now, a question. From $\mid fg\mid=\mid f\mid \mid g\mid<a.b$, I see multiple conditional possibilities of implications. All of them are summarized by $\mid f\mid>a$ or $\mid g\mid>b$? Can you explain me this? I'm thinking it as a problem like $c.d<a.b$ for $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You have your inequality backward. What you need to show is "if $|fg|>ab$, then either $|f|>a$ or $|g|>b$." This is equivalent to "if $|f|\leq a$ and $|g|\leq b$, then $|fg| \leq ab$."

Comment: Contraposition was far away from my mind. Thanks for your help!